# javascript, is there a way to set a (smaller) threshold on touchmove event

Tags: javascript, events, threshold, touchmove

At this moment my touch input device generates a `touchmove` event (after a `touchstart` event) AFTER a number of pixels have been moved (I think it's about 10 pixels)
This means that when using this technique to draw with my finger on the canvas, the first part of a curve is always a straight line with length 10 pixels.
I want a `touchmove` event after just 2 or 3 pixels after the `touchstart` event. Is there some sort of threshold I can manipulate?

Comment: Does the touch event get called multiple times during these 10 pixels? If so, you could simply use them to track the movement.

Comment: Try adding the CSS `touch-action: pinch-zoom;` to your canvas. This will allow the user to zoom with a two-finger touch, but not pan the view with a single finger. In particular this means the browser doesn't have to "wait" to differentiate different types of touches and may be able to respond instantly. Alternatively, "update" your code to use `pointer` events instead of `touch`.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you receive a `touchstart` event, add a listener that records `pointermove` events, storing the event coordinates to an array.

Then, when you receive your `touchmove` event, you will have the pointer location history from when the `touchstart` was received.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the pointer event. I never heard of it. I was able to rewrite a code-snippet found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Using_Pointer_Events

Comment: @StefanHesman Great. This tool I wrote may be handy, it displays all the pointer events (and the MouseEvent 'click'): [Terry's Test of Pointer Events](https://terrymorse.com/devtools/pointerevents/index.html)